# Home folder quicklist not showing quicklist on right click unless it's open

Tags: unity, quicklists

This just started happening, I go to right click the home folder icon to get to my video folder, and it just says

Open new window

---

Home Folder

---

Unlock from launcher

But when I click on the home folder it shows the quick list.  I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when nautilus crashes.  In Gnome and Unity sessions, nautilus is run on login, and manages the desktop background.  That process is running whether you have a nautilus window open or now.  It's crashing on me right now, because of [bug 1053670](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1053670) in Quantal.  And I'd say it's crashing on you, or not running for some reason.  (What are you running?  Did you update recently?)

When there's no nautilus running, the quicklist becomes a generic one.  And right-clicking on the desktop does nothing.  (I think folders on the desktop might disappear, but I don't have any.)